# FluentValidation.ts multiple validators and messages

Tags: typescript, fluentvalidation

Validating child of parent doesn't display child messages, only parent.

How can I see all the messages for child and parent validations?

```
interface IItem {
    id: number;
    subItem: ISubItem;
    customSubItem: ICustomSubItem;
}
interface ISubItem {
    someNumber: number;
}
interface ICustomSubItem {
    someNumber: number;
}

class CustomSubItemValidator extends Validator<ICustomSubItem> {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.ruleFor('someNumber')
            .greaterThan(2)
            .withMessage('Please enter a number');
    }
}
class SubItemValidator extends Validator<ISubItem> {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.ruleFor('someNumber')
            .greaterThan(2)
            .withMessage('Please enter a number');
    }
}
class ItemValidator extends Validator<IItem> {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.ruleFor('id')
            .greaterThan(0)
            .withMessage('Please enter your an id');

        this.ruleFor('subItem')
          .setValidator(() => new SubItemValidator());

        this.ruleFor('customSubItem')
          .setValidator(() => new CustomSubItemValidator());

        this.ruleFor('subItem')
            .must((subItem, item) => {
              return subItem.someNumber > item.customSubItem.someNumber
            })
            .withMessage('Sub item number should be greater then custom sub item');
    }
}
const itemValidator = new ItemValidator();
console.log(itemValidator.validate({
  id: 1, 
  subItem: { someNumber: 1 }, 
  customSubItem: { someNumber: 2 }
}));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've only just come across this, so apologies that you've had to wait for a while for a reply!

Unfortunately, showing both the property-level validation errors and the child-level validation errors for an object property isn't supported. We can only set a single value for the property in the errors object - it can't be both a string and an object.

This behaviour is similar to the behaviour for a simple property, in that the first failing rule is what produces the error message in the errors object - if there are multiple failing validations we still only show the first.

Essentially, you'll need to decide whether the property-level validation rule should apply first or the child-level validations.

Property-level first:

```js
this.ruleFor('subItem')
  .must((subItem, item) => {
    return subItem.someNumber > item.customSubItem.someNumber
  })
  .withMessage('Sub item number should be greater then custom sub item')
  .setValidator(() => new SubItemValidator());
```

Child-level first:

```js
this.ruleFor('subItem')
  .setValidator(() => new SubItemValidator())
  .must((subItem, item) => {
    return subItem.someNumber > item.customSubItem.someNumber
  })
  .withMessage('Sub item number should be greater then custom sub item');
```

I really hope this helps, and if you have any more issues please feel free to [raise an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/AlexJPotter/fluentvalidation-ts/issues) - you should get a quicker reply there as I don't scan Stack Overflow all that often!